# What are all these requests?

Tags: security, hacking, requests

I was checking my server's web server log where I'm installing a wordpress website, and found all these requests, the site is new!

Should I be worried? Is my site hacked or something? I don't understand anything of it. Replaced my website with "ooooo.com"

```
2022/07/18 19:51:07 [error] 27501#27501: *3184 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.70.147.9, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/apikey/apikey.php?test=hello HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com"
2022/07/17 21:33:56 [error] 27501#27501: *2139 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.69.71.59, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/sodium_compat/ccx/index.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "http://oooooo.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/ccx/index.php"
2022/07/17 13:44:20 [error] 27501#27501: *1882 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.70.126.33, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/ubh/up.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "www.bing.com"
2022/07/17 13:42:37 [error] 27501#27501: *1840 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.69.69.84, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /.well-known/alfacgiapi HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "www.bing.com"
2022/07/17 13:41:58 [error] 27501#27501: *1832 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.69.68.206, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/wpconfig.bak.php?act=sf HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "www.bing.com"
2022/07/17 13:41:41 [error] 27501#27501: *1829 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.69.69.84, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/mu-plugins/db-safe-mode.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "www.bing.com"
2022/07/17 13:41:25 [error] 27501#27501: *1816 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.69.70.217, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/wp-atom.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "www.bing.com"
2022/07/17 11:33:31 [error] 27501#27501: *1722 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.68.50.121, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/seoo/sym403bp.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "http://oooooo.com/wp-content/plugins/seoo/sym403bp.php"
2022/07/17 09:49:41 [error] 27501#27501: *1669 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.70.214.169, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-security-enforcements/wwdv.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "http://oooooo.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-enforcements/wwdv.php"
2022/07/17 07:58:58 [error] 27501#27501: *1642 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.68.238.149, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/contus-video-galleryversion-10/upload1.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com"
2022/07/17 07:30:55 [error] 27501#27501: *1632 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.70.246.129, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/wp-blockdown.php?lt=503c138bd956ccbe9a63967ef1f22dac&a=ZWNobyA0MDk3MjMqMjA7 HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com"
2022/07/17 07:30:55 [error] 27501#27501: *1631 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.70.251.126, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/wp-blockup.php?lt=503c138bd956ccbe9a63967ef1f22dac&a=ZWNobyA0MDk3MjMqMjA7 HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com"
2022/07/16 22:17:19 [error] 27501#27501: *1248 access forbidden by rule, client: 162.158.134.87, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/themes/wordpress-theme-security/icwf.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "http://oooooo.com/wp-content/themes/wordpress-theme-security/icwf.php"
2022/07/16 18:10:09 [error] 27501#27501: *1155 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.71.98.141, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-engine-module/bala.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com"
2022/07/16 18:09:47 [error] 27501#27501: *1153 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.71.94.179, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/ioptimization/IOptimize.php?rchk HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com"
2022/07/16 18:09:43 [error] 27501#27501: *1152 access forbidden by rule, client: 141.101.76.141, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/ioptimizations/bala.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com"
2022/07/16 17:02:12 [error] 27501#27501: *1123 access forbidden by rule, client: 108.162.245.19, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/masterx/snx.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "http://oooooo.com/wp-content/plugins/masterx/snx.php"
2022/07/16 18:09:38 [error] 27501#27501: *1151 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.71.102.75, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/ioptimizations/IOptimizes.php?hamlorszd HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com"
2022/07/16 10:52:07 [error] 27501#27501: *959 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.70.134.151, server: oooooo.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-json-api-disable/x112sucuri.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "http://oooooo.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-json-api-disable/x112sucuri.php"
2022/07/16 01:02:48 [error] 27501#27501: *636 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.70.178.197, server: oooooo.com, request: "POST /wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/guest.vary.php HTTP/2.0", host: "oooooo.com", referrer: "https://oooooo.com/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal internet background noise, bots scanning for vulnerabilities.

Just make sure to keep your WordPress and plugins up-to-date.